# Create Login/User using stored procedure from Azure SQL Database's non master database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

What I need is to create stored procedure inside non master database that will create login and user based on data in database.

It works in SQL Server, but is it possible to do it in Azure SQL Database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's impossible.

**In SQL Database, you must be connected to the master database to create a login.**

Please reference: [SQL Database Logins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current#sql-database-logins).

That means even you have create the stored procedure inside non master database, when you execute it, you may get the error like:

[image]

Hope this helps